# Cannot create a program which will invert string

Tags: c, linux, string, reverse

I am using Linux.
I am trying to write a program in c that will print a string backward.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
    char string[100];
    printf ("Enter string:\n");
    gets (string);
    int length = strlen (string)-1;
    for (length = length; length>=0; length--){
        puts (string[length]);
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
a.c:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘puts’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/stdio.h:668: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
/tmp/cc5rpeG7.o: In function `main':
a.c:(.text+0x29): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I wouldn't use the `length` variable as your loop-counter variable as well personally. It's confusing. Unless you're down the wire on memory, just declare an int or char counter variable. (You can use char here because the length can be at most 100).

Comment: @Stephen: just use an `int`. There's usually no memory saving in using a `char` because the compiler will stuff it into a register, not save it to memory. And the compiler will probably optimise `length` away.

Comment: You can omit the first clause in the for-loop. `length=length` is pointless. `for( ; length>=0; length--) {...}`

Comment: @Philip: I think the complaint is that the variable `length` would be better renamed as `i` or `index` or `pos` or something similar because although it is initialized to the length, it is actually used as an array index, not as the length of anything.

Comment: @Stephen: If someone's got enough memory for the standard library, how common is it that a (local, even) char vs. int matters?  Also, if you say "i = length - 1" at the start of the loop and never use length again, the compiler will most likely optimize it away. [Edit: others seem to have beaten me to it. :)]

Comment: @Philip Potter - Good point. Was just not thinking, and going "Int big! Char small! Char good!". Thanks for that.

Comment: Although blessed by the C99 standard (and C++), it still seems weird to me that you are allowed to omit `return(0);` or `return 0;` from the end of any function that returns an `int`.

Comment: @Jonathan: that was Stephen's *other* complaint, which I agree with :)

Comment: @Jonathan: I do believe it's only `main` that has that special case. Where in the standard does it allow arbitrary `int` functions to omit `retorn 0;`?

Comment: @Philip: I should clarify - yes, it is only `main()` that gets that privilege, and I fail to see a single good reason for introducing that exception into C++.  Once it was in C++, C99 followed for uniformity.  It would have been preferable to allow the ubiquitous but erroneous `void main(){ ... }` which would have the effect of returning success to the environment.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer - I must agree. There may be good programming reasons which I am not aware of, but it confuses me mightly to see any function which is declared to return an int that does not. Even if it is the `main` function and I should totally expect it. >_>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

**NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets()`; it **will** introduce a point of failure in your code.  There's no way to tell `gets()` how big the target buffer is, so if you pass a buffer sized to hold 10 characters and there's 100 characters in the input stream, `gets()` will happily store those extra 90 characters in the memory beyond the end of your buffer, potentially clobbering something important.  Buffer overruns are an easy malware exploit; the Morris worm specifically exploited a `gets()` call in sendmail.

Use `fgets()` instead; it allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to read from the input stream.  However, unlike `gets()`, `fgets()` will save the terminating newline character to the buffer if there's room for it, so you have to account for that:

```
char string[100]; 
char *newline;
printf("Enter a string: ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);
newline = strchr(buffer, '\n');      // search for the newline character
if (newline)                         // if it's present
  *newline = 0;                      // set it to zero
```

Now that's out of the way...

Your error is coming from the fact that `puts()` expects an argument of type `char *`, but you're passing an argument of type `char`, hence the "pointer from integer without cast" message (`char` is an integral type).  To write a single character to stdout, use `putchar()` or `fputc()`.

Answer (score 11):

Forget that the function `gets()` exists - it is lethal.  Use `fgets()` instead (but note that it does not remove the newline at the end of the line).

You want to put a single character at a time: use `putchar()` to write it to stdout.  Don't forget to add a newline to the output after the loop.

Also, `for (length = length; length >= 0; length--)` is not idiomatic C.  Use one of:

- `for ( ; length >= 0; length--)`
- `for (length = strlen(string) - 1; length >= 0; length--)`
- `for (int length = strlen(string) - 1; length >= 0; length--)`

The last alternative uses a feature added to C99 (which was available in C++ long before).

Also, we could debate whether `length` is the appropriate name for the variable.  It would be better renamed as `i` or `pos` or something similar because, although it is initialized to the length of the input, it is actually used as an array index, not as the length of anything.

*Subjective*: Don't put a space between the name of a function and its parameter list.  The founding fathers of C don't do that - neither should you.

---

#### Why is gets() lethal?

The first Internet worm - the [Morris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) worm from 1988 - exploited the `fingerd` program that used `gets()` instead of `fgets()`.   Since then, numerous programs have been crashed because they used `gets()` and not `fgets()` or another alternative.

The fundamental problem is that `gets()` does not know how much space is available to store the data it reads.  This leads to 'buffer overflows', a term which can be searched for in your favourite search engine that will return an enormous number of entries.

If someone types 150 characters of input to the example program, then `gets()` will store 150 characters in the array which has length 100.  This never leads to happiness - it usually leads to a core dump, but with carefully chosen inputs - often generated by a Perl or Python script - you can probably get the program to execute arbitrary other code.  This really matters if the program will ever be run by a user with 'elevated privileges'.

Incidentally, `gets()` is likely to be removed from the Standard C library in the next release (C1x - see n1494 from [WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/PostColorado.htm)).  It won't vanish from actual C libraries for a long time yet (20 years?), but it should be replaced with this implementation (or something similar):

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
char *gets(char *buffer)
{
    assert("Probability of using gets() safely" == 0);
}
```

---

*One other minor detail, discussed in part under the comments to the main question.*

The code shown is clearly for C99; the declaration of `length` part way through the function is invalid in C89.  Given that, it is 'OK' for the `main()` function not to explicitly return a value, because the C99 standard follows the lead of the C++ standard and allows you to omit the return from `main()` and the effect is the same as `return(0);` or `return 0;` at the end.

As such, the program in this question cannot strictly be faulted for not having a `return` at the end.  However, I regard that as one of the more peculiar standardizing decisions, and would much prefer it if the standards had left that provision out - or done something more radical like allowing the ubiquitous but erroneous `void main()` observing that when control returns from that, the result is that a success status is returned to the environment.  It isn't worth fighting to get that aspect of the standard changed - sadly - but as a personal style decision, I don't take advantage of the licence granted to omit the final `return` from `main()`.  If the code has to work with C89 compilers, it should have the explicit `return 0;` at the end (but then the declaration of `length` has to be fixed too).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use recursion to do it. I think it looks nicer then when using a loop.

Just call the method with your string, and before printing the char in the method, call the method again with the same string, minus the first char.

This will print out you string in reversed order.

Comment: This works if you're not tight on memory and have small strings. You will get an explosion in stack and memory usage for any non trivial size strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `putchar` instead of `puts`

So this loop:

```
for (length = length; length>=0; length--){
    puts (string[length]);
}
```

Will be:

```
for (length = length; length>=0; length--){
    putchar (string[length]);
}
```

`putchar` will take a single char as a parameter and print it to `stdout`, which is what you want. `puts`, on the other hand, will print the whole string to `stdout`. So when you pass a single char to a function that expects a whole string (char array, **NULL** terminated string), compiler gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Use `putc` or `putchar`, as `puts` is specified to take a `char*` and you are feeding it a `char`.